# Windows: прикрепить консоль к фоновому процессу

Tags: c++, c, windows, cmd, процесс

Есть задача: подключиться к запущенному ***в фоне*** процессу Windows для отправки сигнала (если в терминологии Windows так можно сказать) для завершения работы процесса (Ctrl+C).
Моя идея заключается в том, чтобы создать консоль и приаттачить ее к фоновому процессу. Выбрал для этих целей ***С***.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void logError() 
{ 
    ...
}

int main() {
    if (AttachConsole(123)) {
        
    } else {
        logError();
    }
}
```

Запуск cmd под админом. Получаю ошибку: `GetLastError = Отказано в доступе`.

**Возможно ли приаттачить новую консоль к фоновому процессу (без своей консоли)?**

Comment: Заверни фоновый процесс на сокет или именованный канал какой-нибудь

Comment: Как мне это поможет? Можете более развернуто написать?

Comment: Для того чтоб отправить Ctrl+c консоль не нужна. Используй os.kill

Comment: Насколько понимаю речь о python?

Comment: ну я образно...

Comment: попробуй https://stackoverflow.com/a/15281070/2101808

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12899190/2101808

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем.

Если посмотреть [документацию](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/attachconsole), то можно увидеть, из-за чего возникает ваша ошибка.

> **A process can be attached to at most one console. If the calling process is already attached to a console, the error code returned is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED**. If the specified process does not have a console, the error code returned is ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE. If the specified process does not exist, the error code returned is ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

И еще описание функции.

> **Attaches the calling process to the console of the specified process as a client application.**

То есть эта функция используется не для подключения консоли К какому-то процессу, а для взятия консоли ИЗ чужого процесса.
Если же вы уверены, что вам нужно подключить консоль какого-то левого процесса к процессу, из которого зовете **AttachConsole**, то вот ещё информация:

> A process can use the FreeConsole function to detach itself from its console. If other processes share the console, the console is not destroyed, but the process that called FreeConsole cannot refer to it. A console is closed when the last process attached to it terminates or calls FreeConsole. After a process calls FreeConsole, it can call the AllocConsole function to create a new console or AttachConsole to attach to another console.

То есть вы должны сначала отсоединиться от уже существующей консоли, позвав **FreeConsole**

Comment: Спасибо за полезную информацию! Значит AttachConsole мне не поможет. Я отредактировал вопрос